# how to schedule an osgi bundle in fuse servicemix?

Tags: osgi, quartz-scheduler, apache-servicemix

i want to restart an osgi bundle at a particular time for the day .i am using apache-servicemix-4.3.0-fuse-02-00.

console wise i want to do this . if my bundle id is 210

```
osgi:stop 210

osgi:start 210
```

how can i schedule this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your servicemix has ssh console enabled you could use:

```
ssh smx@IP_TO_FRAMEWORK -p 8101 osgi:stop 210
ssh smx@IP_TO_FRAMEWORK -p 8101 osgi:start 210
```

However, you need to insert the password for the smx user here... I've not found how to use a key-base authentication here. (ssh-copy-id does not work..)

An other solution would be to drop the bundle into the deploy directory. Probably a simple touch would be enough. (I do not know, if changing the timestamps would be enough to trigger a re-installation.)

And a third option: Writing a bundle which will start/stop the other bundle, given a Java [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) which will perform the restart task once a day...

But you should check if you could not change the bundle, so it does not require a daily reboot.

Comment: i haves used the 3rd option using quartz ..working fine thank you